# How to fix React filter search bar

Tags: reactjs

I'm developing a react comparator. 
I'm new in react and I just finished to settle my basic form to let my user filter their research.

I created a function to test the first filter but the console doesn't let me see my result, show errors neither. Just quickly shut down the info on the console.

I'm stuck... I really don't understand my problem, why the function bind on my function shutdown directly when I run it. the `filterClick()`

I already test this function apart, on my App.js file first. And all was ok. So I'm pretty sure my function is correct. Moreover the console don't show any error but I can keep the result open in the console.

The database attached is a simple json object.

Let see the code attached.

Thanks a lot for your help.

```
import React from "react";
import dataShop from '../dataShop.json'

class Filters extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedOption: "option1",
      zip_code: "",
      cabinePhoto: false,
      bornePhoto: false,
      helioBooth: false
    };

    //    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChanges = e => {
    const input = e.target;
    const name = input.name;
    const value = input.type === "checkbox" ? input.checked : input.value;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  };

  filterClick = () => {
    //utiliser find() pour trouver un seul élément
    //utiliser filter() pour trouver plusieurs éléments et créer un nouveau

    const dataFilter = dataShop.filter(dataShop => (dataShop.Cabine_photo === "OUI") && (dataShop.Helio_booth === "OUI"))
    console.log(dataFilter);

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <h1>Filtrer la recherche</h1>
        <div className="form-check">
          <label>
            <input
              name="selectedOption"
              type="radio"
              value="particuliers"
              checked={this.state.selectedOption === "particuliers"}
              onChange={this.handleChanges}
            />
            Particulier
          </label>
        </div>

        <div className="form-check">
          <label>
            <input
              name="selectedOption"
              type="radio"
              value="pros"
              checked={this.state.selectedOption === "pros"}
              onChange={this.handleChanges}
            />
            Pros
          </label>
        </div>

        <label>
          Code postal:
          <input
            type="text"
            name="zip_code"
            value={this.state.zip_code}
            onChange={this.handleChanges}
          />
        </label>
        <br/>
        <label>

          <input
            name="cabinePhoto"
            type="checkbox"
            value={this.state.cabinePhoto}
            onChange={this.handleChanges}
          />Cabine photo:{" "}

          <input
            name="bornePhoto"
            type="checkbox"
            value={this.state.bornePhoto}
            onChange={this.handleChanges}
          />Borne photo:{" "}

          <input
            name="helioBooth"
            type="checkbox"
            value={this.state.helioBooth}
            onChange={this.handleChanges}
          />Héliobooth:{" "}
        </label>
        <button onClick={this.filterClick}>Test Button</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Filters;
```

Comment: Dont you have an issue because `datashop` is a json file and not a js file ?

Comment: Nop it was about what Kamran said just bellow, my page was refreshing onClick because the button is inside the form. Everything is better with a little 
e.preventDefault now    :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're page is refreshing on button click because it's inside form.

You can prevent the form from submitting with

```
filterClick = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  //utiliser find() pour trouver un seul élément
  //utiliser filter() pour trouver plusieurs éléments et créer un nouveau

  const dataFilter = dataShop.filter(dataShop => (dataShop.Cabine_photo === "OUI") && 
  (dataShop.Helio_booth === "OUI"))
  console.log(dataFilter);

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working like a charm.

I'm still always doing these kinds of stupid errors... Thanks u so much

Have a nice day

Comment: if it solves your issue please accept it as an answer. Thanks